# How can I get 'system("source ~/.bash_profile")' to work with current shell?

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, shell

I am updating the bash file programmatically. And at the end of the script, I called `system("source ~/.bash_profile")` to source the bash file. However, the bash file did not get updated in the current shell.

After some research, I found out that `system()` executes within a subshell. Hence (I think) the current shell is not updated with the latest bash file.

It seems that other methods of calling shell commands do not execute them in the current shell too. i.e. backtick, `exec`, `open3`, `open4`.

How do I call a shell command that will update the current shell, without opening a new shell (to break the current work flow)?

I am looking at these commands including

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
alias something="echo something"
```

Update: The suggested answer works. Hence, I am calling `system("kill -SIGUSR1 #{Process.ppid}")` to source the .bash_profile. Note that if you are on mac, you should place the suggested code on `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your <s>.bashrc</s>.bash_profile:

```
sigusr1() {
   source ~/.bash_profile
   echo 'wow! I feel refreshed!'
}

trap sigusr1 SIGUSR1
```

Now, from your program, find out the bash pid (may be just getppid()) and send SIGUSR1 to it using kill().

You'll have fun if you shoot the wrong process! It's some way to make new contacts, especially to those people who just got their processes killed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But sending a kill -SIGUSR1 seems to just kill the bash process. and print "[Process completed]". I am using mac. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a bash available for mac? It's important that you trap SIGUSR1 in the shell, using the code I just wrote. You can verify that it worked by just typing the command "trap" - that should show you the function to be executed upon SIGUSR1

Comment: Wow great! it works like a charm! 

So I basically place this code in .bash_profile instead of .bashrc since mac uses .bash_profile instead of .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, from a program run from the shell, source a script in the parent shell.

That `source` command or a similar alias will, when run from the shell directly, cause the changes to take effect in the current shell though. But in that case you need to write your profile/rc carefully so as to be safe to re-run that way.